# Alias for clang options?

Tags: c, bash, shell, alias, zsh

I got a question, at school we compile C with this command :

```
clang -o filename -O0 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra filename.c
```

and I'd like to make an alias such as `clang-c` which contains all these options

I tried also `clang-c='clang -O0 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra'` but impossible like this to set the name of the output file..

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: But why you need set name of output file in alias? Alias usually contains common params only, so define `alias clang-c='clang -O0 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra'` and then use it like `clang-c -o filename filename.c`

Comment: Or you could really just use a Makefile

Comment: make yourself familiar with `make` or another build tool and you'll probably never call your C compiler directly for any non-trivial program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you a Makefile example:

```
INCPATH = includes/
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I $(INCPATH) -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fPIC -O2
LDFLAGS = -shared
TARGET = libmy_malloc_$(HOSTTYPE).so
LINK_NAME = libmy_malloc.so
SRC =   malloc.c internal.c

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
RM = rm -vf
LN  = ln

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)
    $(LN) -s $(TARGET) $(LINK_NAME)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(TARGET) $(LINK_NAME)

re: fclean all
```

You can set all of your flag on the `CFLAGS` line!

Comment: Thanks man, that's i actually do while not finding what i want, but i'm looking for an alias, i actually use only one file per one file, so.. but thanks man, i'll  use this :)

Comment: the posted answer produces a library,, not what the OP ask for.  And the posted answer is missing a few key statements like: `.PHONY :fclean re clean all`   And once the $(CC) recipe line will produce a linked library file, so why the extra recipe line  $(LN) that will do little beyond changing the library name?